# Help identify this small spiney praying mantis?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Trying to identify this praying mantis for a short film. It's found on the wild cosmos flower. It's found when the flower is in bloom at this time of year (February) in Harare, Zimbabwe.

[image: praying mantis]

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a species of Sub-Saharan [flower mantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flower_mantis) in the genus [***Pseudocreobotra***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocreobotra).

Specifically, it resembles the **spiny flower mantis** [***Pseudocreobotra wahlbergi***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocreobotra_wahlbergi).

[image]

<sup>© [2013-2018 carlarush](https://carlarush.deviantart.com/art/pseudocreobotra-wahlbergii-348684529)</sup>

The species gets its name from the spiny structures on its abdomen. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocreobotra_wahlbergi), the color is variable:

> being typically greenish, but it can equally be yellowish, pinkish or reddish

According to [here](http://www.mantisonline.eu/view/species/mantids/pseudocreobotra/index.php), you can determine the sex of your specimen by counting the "abdominal appendages" (i.e., spikes):

> females have just 5 abdominal-appendages on the underside, however males have 6

[image]

<sup>© [2004 Steffi Schuttauf](http://www.mantisonline.eu/index.php?lan=en&show=species_mantids_view&content=%7B%22subshow%22:%22species_mantids%22,%22level_left_view%22:%22%22,%22level_left_species%22:%22index%22,%22species%22:%22index%22,%22genus%22:%22pseudocreobotra%22,%22level_left_species_mode%22:%22%22%7D)</sup>

This might also be ***P. ocellata***, which would be able to be distinguished from *P. wahlbergi* based on its smaller adult size [[source](http://www.mantisonline.eu/view/species/mantids/pseudocreobotra/index.php)].

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you so much for the identification. I will be sure to send you the short clip when completed. Many thanks from Zimbabwe

Comment: No problem @WildZimbo. Don't forget to click the checkmark to indicate  the answer as "accepted" if you're satisfied. Thanks!